# Http listener running on background worker

Tags: c#, httplistener

I have few questions about http listener. First of all is it good practice to run http listener inside an async backgroundWorker task? Or should I use Thread or Task?

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8000/");
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
    listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;

    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        var result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);
        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
}

private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
}
```

Second question is my example right, for accepting multiple client requests at same time?